# static code analysis tool for detecting SOLID principles violation

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, solid-principles

I'm looking into metrics reported by SonarQube and there are measures like Cognitive complexity which are useful to identify hardly maintainable code. But I found that there are no measures indicating violating SOLID principles. 
Are there static code analysis tools for Java that can report on SOLID principles violation?

Comment: I heard, SonarQube takes care of ensuring SOLID principles are followed, but couldn't find how it works